# Question regarding calculating acceleration due to gravity on planet Mercury

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

I was asked to calculate the acceleration due to gravity on planet Mercury, if the mas of Mercury is $2,99 \times 10^{22} kg $ and its radius is $2,42 \times 10^{3} \ km$. The mass of the object is $10kg$ and the mass of Earth is $6 \times 10^{24} kg$ and the Radius of the Earth is $3,82 \times 10^3 km$.

This question rather puzzled me because I was not sure if my answer is correct or not but let me proceed :
$$\vec{F} = m \vec{a} \label{} = F_g = G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$$
$$ m_1g = G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$$ (Note that $m_2$ = mass of mercury)
$$ g = \frac{( 6.673 \times 10^{-11} \frac{m^2}{kg^2})(2,99 \times 10^{22}kg)}{(2,42 \times 10^{6}\ m)^{2}} $$

I compute my answer to be $0.34 \frac{m}{s^{2}}$.

What really is confusing me is that when I look at my textbook, it shows me the gravitational acceleration due to gravity on mercury to be $3.59 \frac{m}{s^{2}}$.

Can someone please explain to me what the answer that I am getting is giving me? My computation was marked correct in a test but I do not understand what this value is giving me.

Comment: I do not understand how my question that I posted shows that I did not put any effort into it. I showed complete effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value for the mass  of Mercury is not correct.  Check with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)).

The correct value is $3.3\times 10^{23}$ kg.

Comment: Thanks. I just looked at my question paper and textbook. It turned out that they used different values for the mass of Mercury.

Comment: "Different values?" That's off by a full order of magnitude!